# WinUI3 : Incrementally add contents to ListView On scroll

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, desktop-application, winui-3, cppwinrt

I am working on WinUI 3 desktop application in C++. I was trying to achieve an experience where when we scroll [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2), we will incrementally add rows to the end of the listviews dropdown during runtime.

For example, I might have 100,000 results to fit in a list view, I only want to show a limited number of contents in the list view, then as the user scrolls I'll add more contents to the list view.

I was not able to get any scroll-based events in ListView directly, so I extracted the ScrollViewer from the list view and handled the [ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged?view=winrt-22621) event. This event was fired when the scroll happened. But I was not able to get how many rows were scrolled or currently which row is been scrolled.

I want to get how many rows are scrolled so that I can insert enough rows to the end of the ListViews Item Source. It would be of great help if you could help me with this.

Thank You

Comment: [ListView and GridView data virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization) explains how things used to work in "System XAML". I don't know how much of that has made it into WinUI 3.

Comment: Also consider using the [ItemsRepeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/items-repeater) control.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewKeepCoding, This helped in solving the issue, can you mark it as an answer.

Comment: I just made a simple comment. Can't mark it as an answer. Just glad to be of help.